# Derby Database not connecting when deployed as a an executable jar but works fine in Jdeveloper

Tags: database, deployment, jar, derby, jdeveloper

Hi I have a problem with my Java program, when I run the application within JDeveloper, the program works fine, it connects to the derby database properly.
When I create a executable jar i get the following error no suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/c:..../dbcam

i have tried the following

```
    { public void DoConnect3( ) {

  try {
       Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
       // conenct to the database
      // String host ="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/dbCam";
       //String host ="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/Users/nasir/SkyDrive/Java/db_Backup/dbCam";
       String host ="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/Users/nasir/.netbeans-derby/dbCam";
       String uName ="userCam";
       String uPass ="cam";
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);
       stmt = con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
       //String sql = "SELECT * FROM tableCustomer";
       String sql = "SELECT * FROM tableTroubleshooting";
       //String tsss = Integer.toString(tss);
       //String sql = "SELECT * FROM tableTroubleshooting where ProbID  "+"'"+tsss+"'";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
       rs.next();

   }
```

That still doesn't do much only shows me message saying org.apache.derby.clientdriver.

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the *exact* exception and the full stack trace. If Class.forName() throws a ClassNotFoundException, then the problem is that you don't have that class in your CLASSPATH. Try running your program with --verbose=class to learn more about where the Java runtime is looking for your class files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you're using is a ClientDriver url, not an EmbeddedDriver url. You need to add the correct jar and load the correct driver.

HTH

D

Comment: Thanks for the reply i have changed the url, i already have the jars in the library class path its still not connecting when deployed as a executable jar {    public void DoConnect3() {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            String host = "jdbc:derby:C:/Users/nasir/.netbeans-
    }

Comment: I'm using the correct one but still not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953665/jar-file-does-not-execute-with-db-connection