# Jar file does not execute with DB connection

Tags: java, javafx, derby, dbconnection

I'm building a project with `Derby DB` It works just fine when I run it in `Netbeans` and also as jar file when I use DB as `Network Client` with `derbyclient.jar`. But the problem is I have to distribute it so I use Embedded mode of `Derby DB`, As I provide `derby.jar`. And followed the instructions [Provided Here](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html). The only deference between Embedded & Network is we have to use this DB path (short DB name path)

```
dbPath = "jdbc:derby:Mail_Client_Ref_Fiverr";
```

Instead of (full with localhost and port)

```
dbPath = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Mail_Client_Ref_Fiverr";
```

And in `Class.forName` (EmbeddedDriver)

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
```

Instead of (ClientDriver)

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
```

But Its not working even on my own Laptop. I also tried it on my friend's laptop the problem is same.

I'm using `Java 8u121` and its JavaFX project. Help me understand why its not working.

When I double-click on jar file it show a context manu with 3 options

1. Java(TM) Platform SE binary
2. Java Plateform SE binary
3. WinRAR

In networking mode when I click on the 1st option above it works. But in Embedded mode it does not work at all.

**Edit:** When I execute with 1st option it through db connection error. With 2nd option it says unable to install java.

Comment: What does "it does not work at all" mean? What behavior do you get? Error messages? Provide the exact message text. Exceptions? Provide the complete exception stack trace.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Question Edited

Comment: Thanks, but you neither provided the exact message text, nor the complete exception stack trace.